# How to print data between two line pattern in shell script

Tags: python, html, bash, shell, sh

I am using html2text converter to convert html to text . Next thing i want to do is - extract data between 2 lines. The conveted html data looks like

```
 ***** Test Summary *****
tests 18
     *class 
***** Failed tests *****
Device       Class       Test
Nexus        addition    generateBill
some data
***** Packages *****
Package
some data
***** Classess *****
some data
```

I want go get data between ***** Failed tests ***** and ***** Packages *****

command to generate html2text looks like below
html2text /Path/page.html

I tried with

```
html2text /Path/page.html | awk '/***** Failed tests *****/,/***** Packages *****/'
```

but its not working

Comment: To my surprise it's working here using GNU awk as-is. How is it _its not working_ over there? The correct syntax of course is to escape the regex characters `*` by prepending each of them with a `\*`, ie. `.../\*\*...`.

Comment: can you give me the exact command ? so i can test here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to by comment above:

```
$ html2text /Path/page.html | awk '/\*\*\*\*\* Failed tests \*\*\*\*\*/,/\*\*\*\*\* Packages \*\*\*\*\*/'
```

Tested succesfully with gawk, mawk, busybox awk and original-awk (awk version 20121220).

Comment: Your regex is correct. but in my case above command retrurns black output. I had save that result of html2text /Path/page.html in text file and i get the strange output. Its convert all text diffrently like  ***** Test Summary *****
 becomes  ********** TTeesstt SSuummmmaarryy *****. and some of text becomes _s_o_m_e _d_a_t_a